# How can I establish a connection between my SQL Server 2017 database with a SaaS-based server?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, linked-server, saas

I use a SQL Server 2017 database to perform ad-hoc data analytics activities to support my team. In order to source data from various databases, I either mount a backup on my environment (if the target DB holding the data I’m after is also SQL Server) or use linked servers to establish a direct connection (where I need data from Oracle or iSeries).

More recently though I’m coming across SaaS based systems and was wondering if there’s any way I can establish a direct connection between my database and the SaaS database? I’m not sure whether SSIS packages will do the trick. Any pointers would be gratefully appreciated as I’m struggling to get the right, scalable solution for this problem!

Comment: Completely depends on the SaaS system and what it supports

Answer (score 0):

Data integration with SaaS solutions is a mixed bag.  You have to discover on a case-by-case basis what integration or data export functionality each SaaS application has.  Few will allow any kind of direct database access, but you might find an ETL tool that has pretty broad connectivity.

In Azure you can look at [Logic Apps Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/connector-reference-logicapps-connectors), and [Power Query Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/).  Or products like [Boomi](https://boomi.com/).  Which have connectors for many popular SaaS Applications.